# if statement failing to run

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have an if statement that doesn't seem to quite work and I'm not entirely sure why and was wondering if anyone saw something that I didn't

```
$(".nav_btn, .bow_nav_btn").click(function () {
    var jthis = this;

    if ($(jthis).hasClass("bow_nav_btn")) {
        $('.bow_nav_btn').removeClass('bow_nav_selected');
        $('.bow_nav_btn').addClass('bow_nav_unselected');
        $(this).removeClass('bow_nav_unselected');
        $(this).addClass('bow_nav_selected');
    } else if ($(jthis).hasClass("bow_unselect")) {
        $("bow_nav").slideUp();
    } else($(jthis).hasClass("bow_select")) {
        $("bow_nav").slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$("bow_nav")` check your selectors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have invalid selectors at the end too, along with the already mentioned `else if` issue.

The whole code should probably be similar to:

```
$(".nav_btn, .bow_nav_btn").click(function () {
    var jthis = this;

    if ($(jthis).hasClass("bow_nav_btn")) {
        $('.bow_nav_btn').removeClass('bow_nav_selected');
        $('.bow_nav_btn').addClass('bow_nav_unselected');
        $(this).removeClass('bow_nav_unselected');
        $(this).addClass('bow_nav_selected');
    } else if ($(jthis).hasClass("bow_unselect")) {
        $(".bow_nav").slideUp(); // <-- .bow_nav instead of just bow_nav
    } else if($(jthis).hasClass("bow_select")) { //<-- aded if to else
        $(".bow_nav").slideDown(); // <-- .bow_nav instead of just bow_nav
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that is his error. He is missing an if in the last else.

Comment: @th3falc0n: Hence I said **too**, no need to repeat the if-else issue again but I add it as well then for completeness.

Comment: @th3falc0n that is a big error.. nothing's going to happen if he doesn't use a correct selector - making it seem like his if statement isn't running

Comment: @th3falc0n: I just didn't want to repeat the `else if` again but off course, you are correct, the answer should be complete, no point fixing the selector if the else clause never runs. Thanks for pointing it out though in the comment +1ed your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Your last `else` should be an `else if` *or* you should remove the condition and write it as just:

```
else {
   //snip
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing an `if` keyword in that final `else` clause.

```
} else($(jthis).hasClass("bow_select")) {
```

should be:

```
} else if ($(jthis).hasClass("bow_select")) {
```